# Why is the global variable not being defined

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have a function that is suppose to assign whichever the new date for an id, while trying to store it as a global variable for late but for some reason it always gets stored as undefined, even though it shows when I call the function in the console.
Please Help!

EDIT!-Placing the second function inside the first passes the variable

```js
//Creating the database object
var db = new PouchDB('spiff');
console.log ("Database created Successfully.");
var temp_id;
function startup()
{ 
   //Prompt user
   fullName=prompt("What is your full name?");
   gender=prompt("Are you a male or female?");
   age=prompt("How old are you?");
   area=prompt("Where are you from?");

   //Make new profile with new info
   var lift= new Date();
   var userInfo= 
   { 
    _id: lift.toISOString(),
    user: " ",
    pass: " ",
    fullname: fullName,
    gender: gender,
    age:age,
    area: area,
   };
   temp_id=lift.toISOString();

 //places data into database
 db.put(userInfo, function callback(err, result)
 {
     if (!err) 
  {
        console.log('userInfo saved');
        console.log(temp_id);        
     }
  else
  {
   console.log(err)
  }
   }
   );

 var today = new Date()
 var curHr = today.getHours()

 if (curHr < 12) 
 {
    document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = ('Good Morning ' + fullName);
 } 
 else if (curHr < 18) 
 {
    document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = ('Good Afternoon ' + fullName);
 } 
 else 
 {
    document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = ('Good Evening ' + fullName);
 }
}

function newAdd(){
 console.log(temp_id);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <script src="js/pouchdb-7.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <title>Profile Display</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="startup()">
     <h1>Spiff Co. Savings Goals</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <h2>
         <div id="welcome"></div>
        </h2>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <nav>
         <a href="index.html">Profile Display</a>
         <a href="add.html">Add Profile</a>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Next html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <script src="js/pouchdb-7.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <title>Add Profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html">Profile Display</a>
            <a href="add.html">Add Profile</a>
        </nav>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <h2>Create a New Profile</h2>
        <button type="button" onclick="newAdd()"> Click Here!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass a global variable to a different page? From your 2 HTML snippets I can only guess that these are 2 separate pages. If so, what you are trying to achieve requires the use of localStorage or Cookies.

Comment: Oooh...Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you misspelled it. You defined `var temp` as your global variable. But in your function you use `temp_id`. That is not the same. After replacing all `temp_id` in your function with `temp`it should work as expected.

EDIT: I see you edited the mistake. Also, if this is the full code, then you are not calling the functions you defined. It would explain why it works in the console, since you are actually calling the function.

Comment: That's my mistake, it has 2 separate html files along with it